# <center> making new line

Tags: html, css

Alright so I'm trying to create a top bar line the one somewhat at the top of this one. I used the  tag and when I try and put anything else on the line it goes to the next line. My code looks like this:

```
<div id="topbar">
    <center>
        <img src="images/hehe.png" />
    </center>
    ALSO ON TOP BAR!
</div>
```

but instead the image is on the top bar and "ALSO ON TOP BAR!" goes to the next line and is no longer in the top bar. How do I fix this?

Comment: `<center>` is long time deprecated. Use `style="text-align:center;"` instead

Answer (score 3):

```
#topbar
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

and Html is

```
<div id="topbar">
<img src="images/hehe.png" />
ALSO ON TOP BAR!
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5w5pY/)

Don't use `<center>` tag. mention in css stylesheets.. That is the better one..

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="topbar">
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <img src="images/hehe.png" />
        ALSO ON TOP BAR!
    </div>
</div>
```

Using css `text-align:center;` to centralize.

Answer (score 0):

I would refrain from using the center tag set as it is no longer used in HTML.
It's recommended to use CSS for your task.

As mentioned in another thread, text-align: center will fix your issue.
However, I would recommend the following to horizontally center non-textual elements:

```
img {
      display: block; 
      margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This would center your image horizontally.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uberrobert/GPGbn/1/